# Best colour to chroma key in natural lighting

Tags: chroma-key, natural-lighting

What is in natural lighting conditions and in an outdoor setting  (European forest) the best colour to use for an object you later want to use a chroma key projection on to maximize hue contrast? None of the primary colours seem to qualify.

Comment: I really do not understand your question. Do you want to take the photo of a tree, and then cut it? Or this photo is going to be used later as a background?

Comment: @Rafael I will take for example a coloured box into the forest. There I will take a picture of said box. I want to project another image on the space that box is taking up in my picture. What colour should the box be to make this as painless as possible?

Comment: In the forest, I'd guess light blue, but since I'm not a chroma key expert, I'll let someone else write the answer to this question.

Comment: You might want to consider asking how to accomplish your end result instead of how best to do it one particular way.

Comment: @Robin This is a technique I plan to use more often. Therefore I'd prefer the slightly broader question.

Comment: @Weckar E. You missed my point that chroma key might not be the easiest way to do it (not saying it isn't either), so don't limit your options on how to accomplish the task. I was actually suggesting that you broaden the possible answers by not limiting the answers to a specific technique.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I consider there are some rules for chroma keying.

**1.** A color that is the opposite of what is in front of it.

**2.** A bright color, mainly a primary RGB color. This way one channel will have enough contrast to be used as a mask. This limits the options to R, G, B but you could use bright orange for example and change the hue to extract a mask. This color choice is taking rule 1 first.

**3.** If the object in front of the chroma key is semi-transparent probably is better to have a similar color to what the final product will be, to avoid halos. White, for example.

Semi-transparent also includes out of focus stuff, in this case a close up of leaves.

Comment: I hadn't considered using a hue shift to extract the mask through a single colour channel. +1 for you, with a possible accept if no one else pops their head in :)

Answer (score 0):

This can also be accomplished via a simple mask that can be reasonably easily created if you use a box that provides a strong colour contrast.  White would probably work well in most forest settings.

Tools like Topaz ReMask make it pretty simple.

I don't know if this is easier than Chroma Key or not, as I haven't used it, but it is how I would do it.